# Android:Sqlite insertion of hardcoded data

Tags: android, sqlite

I have insert two fields namely truck_id and employee_id in a table.

Sorry to ask this question. But as I am new to android,please help me out.

```
public void insert(String[] employeeName,int[] truck_id){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues vals = new ContentValues();

    vals.put(COLUMN_TRUCKID, "CM-3456");
    vals.put(COLUMN_NAME,"Sachin");
    //vals.put(KEY_PIN, "12345");

    vals.put(COLUMN_TRUCKID, "HR-6788");
    vals.put(COLUMN_NAME,"Sameer");
    //vals.put(KEY_PIN, "54321");

    vals.put(COLUMN_ID, "AM-6123");
    vals.put(COLUMN_NAME,"Sahu");
    //vals.put(KEY_PIN, "3452");

    db.insert("Login", "John",
            vals);
    db.insert("Login", "Sameer",
            vals);

    db.execSQL(COLUMN_NAME);

    //myDataBase.close();
}
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

`ContentValues` is a `Map`, so it can only contain one entry at a time for each column name. So, you need to insert each item separately after settings its values.

```
vals.put(COLUMN_TRUCKID, "CM-3456");
vals.put(COLUMN_NAME,"Sachin");
db.insert("Login", null, vals);

vals.put(COLUMN_TRUCKID, "HR-6788");
vals.put(COLUMN_NAME,"Sameer");
db.insert("Login", null, vals);
```

Remove this line, or else bad things will happen:

```
db.execSQL(COLUMN_NAME);
```

Comment: Please explain "BAD THINGS"?